# How to customize Orchard's default FormsAuthentication to my own custom authentication

Tags: orchardcms, csla

I need to customize Orchard's default FormsAuthentication to my own custom authentication

Currently FormsAuthenticationService class is checking

```
if (httpContext.IsBackgroundContext() || !httpContext.Request.IsAuthenticated || !(httpContext.User.Identity is FormsIdentity))
        {
            return null;
        }
```

and httpContext.User.Identity is returning as System.Web.Security.FormsIdentity
instead of FormsIdentity i need to check my own identity like Csla.Security.UnauthenticatedIdentity

Comment: Did you try to implement your own `Orchard.Security.Providers.IAuthenticationService`?